# Excel Refusing to Do Any Sorting after 524,161 rows of data

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I'm running into what appears to be a hard limit or something. At exactly 524,162 rows of data, I can no longer sort the data. Someone else claims they did 600,000 just fine. I have 32GB of RAM though my Excel 2013 is only 32-Bit so I guess it can't utilize it all. Perhaps it can only use the first 4GB and perhaps that portion is already taken up by other programs? I'm sitting at 20% utilization. I can't seem to find a way around this though and I need to. Any ideas?

Comment: 524,161 sounds like 512K rows, may be a hardcoded limit.  Try 64-bit Excel.  It's probably not a RAM issue, but possibly some deal with 32-bit integers in Excel.

Comment: It's a work computer which does not offer 64-bit so I can't try it. Someone claimed to do 600,000 though so it doesn't appear hard-coded. Well, unless of course they had 64-bit which I don't know.

Comment: Try it on another computer with Excel installed. Does it work there? If it's a work computer that IT controls, then you should ask you IT why it's not working, since you probably won't be able to apply many of the fixes that may be offered (ie: try repairing Office).

Comment: For compatibility there is no difference in Excel limits between 32 and 64 bit versions.

Comment: [Excel specifications and limits](https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-ca36e2dc-1f09-4620-b726-67c00b05040f)

Comment: I didn't see my exact limit but I can only guess it's limited by available memory. So.... given that I have tons of memory left, perhaps it can't utilize it since it's 32-bit. Any idea how to allow Excel to have the first 2GB or something? Or does excel locally reference and the OS handles the real location? Perhaps it doesn't matter which positions in RAM are available...?